# If_else statements based on multiple columns that creates a score that is averaged based on how many true statements in R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

I have multiple columns that I have put into categories

The data is in categories such as:

```
Q1 Q2 - TS
Q3 - NI
Q4 Q5 Q6 - SALES
```

I want to create a column for each category that gives a score

for example:
[image]

Where each category of questions has a score

```
4 = +1 
-4= +0
NA or 0 = blank/no value
```

so basically, if the category contains 3 questions and 1 question has an na or a 0 it does not add any value to the overall score.

```
Q5 Q6 Q7      SALES_SCORE
na. 4. 0   =.   1/1= 1.
```

(because only one question added value to the overall score)

```
Q5 Q6 Q7      SALES_SCORE
0. -4. -4   =.   (0+0)/2= 0.
```

Ive been trying to create the conditional if_else statements in R but I am having no luck.
this is what ive tried:

```
df$TS_Score <- (sum(if_else(df$Q5 > 0 | df$Q6 >0 | df$Q7 >0, 1,

                     if_else(df$Q5 < 0 | df$Q6 <0 | df$Q7 <0, 0,

                      if_else(df$Q5 == 0 | df$Q6 == 0 | df$Q7 == 0, "",

                       if_else(df$Q5 == NA | df$Q6 == NA | df$Q7==NA,"" 
                        )))))
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of helper functions seem useful:

```
num <- function(x) ifelse(x > 0 & !is.na(x), 1, 0)
den <- function(x) ifelse(x != 0 & !is.na(x), 1, 0)
# test functions
num(c(4, -4, 0, NA)) # 1 0 0 0
den(c(4, -4, 0, NA)) # 1 1 0 0
```

Then calculate each of the desired scores:

```
df$TS_Score <- (num(df$Q1) + num(df$Q2)) / 
  (den(df$Q1) + den(df$Q2))
df$NI_Score <- num(df$Q3) / den(df$Q3)
df$Sales_Score <- (num(df$Q4) + num(df$Q5) + num(df$Q6)) / 
  (den(df$Q4) + den(df$Q5) + den(df$Q6))
```